# Xcode keeps telling me my usage of NSDirectoryEnumerator is wrong.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to instantiate an NSDirectoryEnumerator from a NSFileManager like this

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enum = [fm enumeratorAtURL:*url includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:nil errorHandler:nil];
```

and Xcode keeps coming with an error message that even after reading the complete FileManager and DirectoryManager Documentation doesn't make any sense to me:

**Expected identifier or '('**

Do I have to import anything else than Core Foundation to use `NSDirectoryEnumerator` or is there some special trick to the usage syntax that I am missing?

// edit:

`url` is of course a valid NSURL. Just in case this might come up.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a syntax error, which means your error is with the Objective-C *language*, so no amount of reading the Cocoa *framework* docs will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C and, by extension, Objective-C, `enum` is a keyword. Change the variable name.

Also, you need to remove the asterisk, unless it's a pointer to `NSURL *` (i.e. `NSURL **`) as commented by [@WTP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142019/wtp):

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enum = [fm enumeratorAtURL:*url includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 errorHandler:nil];
                                                  ^
                                              Right here!
```

And the options parameters should be 0, not `nil` as noted by [@omz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573626/omz).

Comment: It in fact is a pointer...forgot about that one. And I now feel very foolish for not thinking of the keyword thingy.

Comment: In addition to that, the asterisk before `url` is wrong and the options parameter should be of type `NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions`, which is an `NSUInteger`, so the default value is `0`, not `nil`.